# What's the recommended way to find out whether a ofstream created a new or appended an existing file?

Tags: c++, file, io

I open a file with something like

```
std::ofstream output(file, std::ios::ate);
```

and want to know whether the a new file was created or an existing one opened.
Of course I could check for file existence before the above line, but the `ofstream` constructor (or its delegates) must have (had) that information. In particular, I wonder whether

```
bool is_appending = output.tellp();
```

would give me the correct information.

Comment: *"the `ofstream` constructor must have (had) that information"* -- Not necessarily.  There are flags you can pass to the C `open()` call that request that if the file does not exist it be created, and if it does it be truncated.  If the constructor is delegating the operation to this call then it may not even know which happened.

Comment: @cdhowie Okay, I edited my question to allow for this.

Comment: @Walter Meh, its not great. That would work to detect either a new file or appending to an empty file.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams ah, okay. that's not too bad. It's actually better (I would want to treat the case of appending to an empty file in the same way as opening a new one).

Comment: @Walter meh. I dunno. I certainly don't like it. Like, it'll always return false for "/dev/null". I guess it really depends on what you are using it for.